# Cassandra is inserting null values in skipped column

Tags: cassandra

Anybody please help me understand why Cassandra is inserting null values in columns that was skipped? Isn't it supposed to skip the column? It should not insert any value (not even null) if I skip the column entirely while inserting data? I am bit confused because as per the following tutorial, data is stored by row key with the columns (the diagram in column family), if it is true then I should not get null for the column.

Or the whole concept I learned about the Cassandra column family is wrong?

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cassandra/cassandra_data_model.htm

**Here is the CQL script**

```
create keyspace test WITH replication =  {'class': 'SimpleStrategy',   'replication_factor': '1'};
create table users (firstname text,lastname text,age int, gender ascii, primary key(firstname))
insert into users(firstname,age,gender,lastname) values("Michael",30,"male","smith");
```

Here, I am skipping a column, but when I run select query, it shows null for that column. Why Cassandra is filling up null in that column?

```
insert into users(firstname,age,gender) values('Jane',23,'female');

select * from users;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Why don't you go to the most comprehensive source of documentation and learning for Cassandra : http://academy.datastax.com ? And it's **free**. The content and tutorialspoint.com is very old and not updated since ages (SuperColumn are deprecated since 2011 - 2012 ...)
2. > Here, I am skipping a column, but when I run select query, it shows null for that column. Why Cassandra is filling up null in that column?

In CQL, null == value is not present **or** value has been deleted

Since you did not insert any value for column *lastname* Cassandra will return **null** (== not present in this case)

Comment: As C* does not do read-before-write, is it not so that C* always has to assume a missing value was deleted and thus always creates a tombstone, even for columns that were never written? In other words, is the state of _not present_ not a hypothetical one when using CQL?

Comment: The states *not present* and *delete* are known for sure at **read time** (CQL SELECT). For INSERT, if you don't specify the column, Cassandra won't do anything (no tombstone). If your insert **null** Cassandra will create tombstone for the column

Comment: Ah, right. I got caught up with the issue with prepared statements and NULLs.